# Razor Inline Template Item Keyword in VB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Check out this code sample from Scott Guthrie's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/scottgu/image_43366964.png

Notice `item` is a reference to the currently executing item in C#, what is the equivalent keyword in VB.NET?

Thanks.

EDIT: I should add here is my actual implementation of a method accepting a template:

```
Public Function RenderInlineTemplate(ByVal template As Func(Of RazorSamplesWeb.Models.SamplesModel, Object)) As IHtmlString
    Return New HtmlString("<div style='display:inline;'>" + template(Model) + "</div>")
End Function
```

And I get this error:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30201:
>   Expression expected.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 101: Line 102:Function with
>   Template: Line
>   103:@RenderInlineTemplate(@@String.Concat(item.Name,
>   " (", item.City, ", ", item.State,
>   ")")) Line 104: Line 105:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a workaround so it appears it isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
@Code
    Dim grid = New WebGrid(Model.Products)
End Code

@grid.GetHtml(
    columns := grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Name", "Product", style := "product"),
        grid.Column("Description", format := Function(i)i.Description),
        grid.Column("Price", format := Function(i) String.Format("${0}", i.Price))

    )
)
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but are you saying there isn't the same level of support as in C#, as C# doesn't require a pure server-side approach?  It seems to me there has to be some way...

Comment: @Brian, what server side approach are you talking about? I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Look at the link I attached... where you have format, it has a mix of client and server content, what you have is a formatted string.  This was an example, my real situation is similar to this, but one where I cannot just write out a server-side string, I need this client/server mix.